# I need help displaying data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning php and I have a problem with a project. I have a database in mysql (localhost) and in it I have 3 tables: categories, products and restaurants, categories and restaurants are linked to products. And when I try to display products of a specified category it doesn't display anything. The connection to the database is good and the queries are good so I have no idea what's wrong. Pleas help.

This is the index.php

```
     <?php

    include_once './database.php';
    include_once './header.php';

    <div class="content" align="center">


        <div id="galery" class="content_block" style="height:400px;"> 
            <div class="galery">
            <img src="./img/gallery/6.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="content_block" style="padding-bottom:10px;">


                    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


           echo '<a href="categories.php?cat='.$row['category'].'"><div class="contentButton inline"><div class="catFood_img foodCategory_1"></div><div>'.$row['category'].'</div></div></a>';



                </div>

        <div class="content_block" style="height:190px" align="center">


                    $query = "SELECT * FROM restourants";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<a href="categories.php?res='.$row['restourant'].'"><div class="restournats inline"><img src="./food/restourants/chens.jpg"></div></a>';

                    }

        </div>
   </div>



  include_once './footer.php';

  ?>
```

And this is the code for categories.php

```
    include_once './database.php';
    include_once './header.php';




   <div class="content" align="center">
   <div class="content_block2">




    $category= (int)(isset($_GET['id_category']) ? $_GET['id_category'] : '');

     $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.id_category=$category";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


        echo '
        <a href="dishes.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><div class="item inline">
        <div class="food_img"><img src="'.$row['img'].'" /></div>
        <div class="title">'.$row['name'].'</div>
        <div class="price inline">Price: '.$row['price'].' €</div><div class="btn">Choose</div>
        </div>
        </a>';
    } 


        </div> 
            </div>


       include_once './footer.php';
```

Comment: side note: your code is very vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. you should sanitize your user inputs and/or use parameterised queries.

Comment: Are you sure you get data from $_GET ?

Comment: try echo $query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **index.php** you are creating the link as

```
echo '<a href="categories.php?cat='.$row['category'].'">
```

(double check `$row['category']` given above is the desired category id value you need)

But in your **categories.php** you are trying to get the category as

```
$category= (int)(isset($_GET['id_category']) ? $_GET['id_category'] : '');
```

Try `$_GET['cat']` instead of `$_GET['id_category']`

Also try `echo $category` and `echo $query` to see if you are getting the desired values.

Comment: I tried echo $query and $category. It doesn't get the id for the category.

Comment: @Novice did you used $_GET['cat']

Comment: Ok glad to know :)